# Getting value from many to many relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to get value from my tables with many to many relationship.
My relation are:
User:

```
public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role',"users_roles","usersid","rolesid");
}
```

Role:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User',"users_roles","usersid","rolesid");
}
```

I did this in my view:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
                    <?php $i++; ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $i }}</td>
                            <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                            <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
                            <td>{{$user->roles->role}}</td>
                        <tr>

@endforeach
```

I'm getting following error:
Undefined index: role

But when i do {{$user->roles}}, I get following:

```
[{"id":1,"role":"Administrator","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"pivot":{"usersid":4,"rolesid":1}}]
```

Can anyone tell me where did i go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
<td>
    @if($user->roles)
        {{$user->roles->first()->role}}
    @else
        No role for this user
    @endif
</td>
```

You need to use [Eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) when you are fetching the users

Comment: I'm getting: Trying to get property of non-object